# Manifolds with zero Chern term

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, semi-riemannian-geometry

Has any study been made of manifolds where the integrand $e(\Omega)$ from the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem (which I gather is called the Euler class) is identically zero?  If so, is there any broader significance to such manifolds or umbrella statement that can be made about them?  I have physics motivation so I'm especially interested in (3,1) Lorentzian manifolds if possible.

Comment: For a compact $n$ dimensional kahler manifold $M$. $M$ has vanishing first real Chern class is sometimes used as the definition of a Calabi–Yau manifold.  Though it is weaker requirement then another standard definition that $M$ has a holomorphic $n$-form that vanishes nowhere.  Calabi–Yau manifolds are important in superstring theory.

Comment: @Elad  Awesome, thanks a million!

Comment: @Elad But we're talking about $c_2$ here for a complex surface.